Ratio of line segments in a projective space

I am struggling to understand where the ratio from the picture comes from. I am I supposed to be considering the cross ratio? It seems like the most obvious point of attack. Here they defined 0 = (0,0,1), 1 = (1,0,1), $\infty$ = (1,0,0)
Any help appreciated, thanks
